# how to change a disabled network adapter configuration by powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I want to changed an networking adapter ip address. For some security reason, we should change it when it is disabled.

I used the following:

```
Set-NetIPAddress  -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 3" -PrefixLength 20 -IPAddress 10.91.62.201
```

But that failed with following message:

```
Set-NetIPAddress : No matching MSFT_NetIPAddress objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress class on the  CIM 
server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPAddress  WHERE ((IPAddress LIKE '10.91.62.201')) AND ((InterfaceAlias LIKE 'Ethernet 3'))
```

Is there anyone who know how to changed a disabed networking adapter configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it through the registry:

Get the adapter object (We need the GUID as the registry identifies the adapters by guid):

```
$adapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | WHERE {$_.DeviceID -eq "1"}
```

Update the registry accordingly:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\$($adapter.guid)" -Name IPAddress -Value "10.91.62.201" -Force
```